# dart recipe file.rename() renames the file but does not update the path in the object

Tags: dart

The dart cookbook recipe 'Renaming a file, directory, or symlink' at https://www.dartlang.org/dart-vm/dart-by-example#renaming-a-file-directory-or-symlink  doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() async {
  // Get the system temp directory.
  var systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;

  // Create a file.
  var file = await new File('${systemTempDir.path}\\foo.txt').create();

  // Prints path ending with `foo.txt`.
  print('The path is ${file.path}');

  // Rename the file.
  await file.rename('${systemTempDir.path}\\bar.txt');

  // Prints path ending with `bar.txt`.
  print('The path is ${file.path}');
}
```

The output shows that the internal path field of the file object has not been changed (although the rename is successful):

```
[Running] dart "d:\src\dart\renameAsOnWeb.dart"
The path is C:\Users\guivh\AppData\Local\Temp\foo.txt
The path is C:\Users\guivh\AppData\Local\Temp\foo.txt

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.327 seconds
```

I have extended / reworked the cookbook example to further investigate this:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() async {
  var systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
  var file = await new File('${systemTempDir.path}\\foo.txt').create();
  print('The file is located at ${file.path}');
  File toDelete;

  var newName = '${systemTempDir.path}\\fubar.toodeloo';
  await file.rename(newName);

  if (await new File(newName).exists() == false) {
    print('The rename failed: there is no ${newName} file');
  } else {
    var newFile = new File(newName);
    print('The rename was succesful');
    var nameChangedInObject = file.path == newName;
    if (nameChangedInObject) {
      print('The path of the file object has changed correctly');
      toDelete = newFile;
    } else {
      print(
          'The path in the file object still is: ${file.path}');
      toDelete = newFile;
    }
    await toDelete.delete();
    print(
        'And now, ${toDelete.path} is gone: ${await toDelete.exists() == false}');
  }
}
```

And this output confirms the fact that the internal path field is not updated with the new name:

```
[Running] dart "d:\src\dart\renamingExample.dart"
The file is located at C:\Users\guivh\AppData\Local\Temp\foo.txt
The rename was succesful
The path in the file object still is: C:\Users\guivh\AppData\Local\Temp\foo.txt
And now, C:\Users\guivh\AppData\Local\Temp\fubar.toodeloo is gone: true

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.369 seconds
```

I am runing the dev version on a windows box:

```
PS D:\src\dart> dart --version
Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.39.0 (Fri Mar 16 00:17:07 2018 +0100) on "windows_x64"
PS D:\src\dart>
```

Can somebody please explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example is wrong. The `File` object [is immutable](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/io/file_impl.dart#L205), so it definitely won't be changed by the rename operation. The example is wrong in expecting so.

Comment: Apparently you are right. But then the official dart-by-example page is in error?